# Is there a way to create multiple instances of CacheManager in Microsoft Enterprise Library, programatically without depending on configuration file

Tags: caching, enterprise-library

We are trying to migrate to use Microsoft Enterprise Library - Caching block. However, cache manager initialization seems to be pretty tied to the config file entries and our application creates inmemory "containers" on the fly. Is there anyway by which an instance of cache manager can be instantiated on the fly using pre-configured set of values (inmemory only).

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to programmatically merge multiple configurations (for the logging block), and this post was almost the answer - except the second builder in the code by Likia overwrites the first builder configuration for me. I found a full solution by utilizing the MergeConfigurationSource here http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/253733

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enterprise Library 5 has a [fluent configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) which makes it easy to programmatically configure the blocks.  For example:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureCaching()
       .ForCacheManagerNamed("MyCache")
       .WithOptions
         .UseAsDefaultCache()
         .StoreInIsolatedStorage("MyStore")
         .EncryptUsing.SymmetricEncryptionProviderNamed("MySymmetric");

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

Unfortunately, it looks like you need to configure the entire block at once so you wouldn't be able to add CacheManagers on the fly.  (When I call `ConfigureCaching()` twice on the same builder an exception is thrown.)  You can create a new `ConfigurationSource` but then you lose your previous configuration.  Perhaps there is a way to retrieve the existing configuration, modify it (e.g. add a new `CacheManager`) and then replace it?  I haven't been able to find a way.

Another approach is to use the `Caching` classes directly.

The following example uses the `Caching` classes to instantiate two `CacheManager` instances and stores them in a static `Dictionary`.  No configuration required since it's not using the container.  I'm not sure it's a great idea -- it feels a bit wrong to me.  It's pretty rudimentary but hopefully helps.

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, CacheManager> caches = new Dictionary<string, CacheManager>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IBackingStore backingStore = new NullBackingStore();
    ICachingInstrumentationProvider instrProv = new CachingInstrumentationProvider("myInstance", false, false,
        new NoPrefixNameFormatter());

    Cache cache = new Cache(backingStore, instrProv);
    BackgroundScheduler bgScheduler = new BackgroundScheduler(new ExpirationTask(null, instrProv), new ScavengerTask(0,
        int.MaxValue, new NullCacheOperation(), instrProv), instrProv);

    CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(cache, bgScheduler, new ExpirationPollTimer(int.MaxValue));
    cacheManager.Add("test1", "value1");
    caches.Add("cache1", cacheManager);

    cacheManager = new CacheManager(new Cache(backingStore, instrProv), bgScheduler, new ExpirationPollTimer(int.MaxValue));
    cacheManager.Add("test2", "value2");            
    caches.Add("cache2", cacheManager);

    Console.WriteLine(caches["cache1"].GetData("test1"));
    Console.WriteLine(caches["cache2"].GetData("test2"));
}

public class NullCacheOperation : ICacheOperations
{
    public int Count { get { return 0; } }
    public Hashtable CurrentCacheState { get { return new System.Collections.Hashtable(); } }
    public void RemoveItemFromCache(string key, CacheItemRemovedReason removalReason) {}
}
```

If expiration and scavenging policies are the same perhaps it might be better to create one `CacheManager` and then use some intelligent key names to represent the different "containers".  E.g. the key name could be in the format "{container name}:{item key}" (assuming that a colon will not appear in a container or key name).

Answer (score 3):

You can using UnityContainer:

```
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        IContainerConfigurator configurator = new UnityContainerConfigurator(unityContainer);

        configurator.ConfigureCache("MyCache1");

        IContainerConfigurator configurator2 = new UnityContainerConfigurator(unityContainer);
        configurator2.ConfigureCache("MyCache2");

        // here you can access both MyCache1 and MyCache2:
        var cache1 = unityContainer.Resolve<ICacheManager>("MyCache1");
        var cache2 = unityContainer.Resolve<ICacheManager>("MyCache2");
```

And this is an extension class for IContainerConfigurator:

```
public static void ConfigureCache(this IContainerConfigurator configurator, string configKey)
    {
        ConfigurationSourceBuilder builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
        DictionaryConfigurationSource configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
        // simple inmemory cache configuration
        builder.ConfigureCaching().ForCacheManagerNamed(configKey).WithOptions.StoreInMemory();
        builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
        EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(configurator, configSource);
    }
```

Using this you should manage an static IUnityContainer object and can add new cache, as well as reconfigure existing caching setting anywhere you want.

Comment: That's a good one.  I came to a similar conclusion and retained a global reference to the container so that the EnterpriseLibraryContainer could be updated on demand.  A general note about the dynamic cache approach (not specifically aimed at you @Reverove) that if adding dynamic caches there is no facility to free unused caches (i.e. Scavenging) so memory use could grow depending on the usage.

Comment: Well, pls tell me clearlier, I think we can setup scavenging in the ConfigureCache method, with the WithOptions call?. Furthermore, we can reuse last used cache as calling ConfigureCache twice on the same cache could not make any memory penaty :-?

Comment: By scavenging of the caches, I mean that the program may create a cache, fill it with data and then never access the cache again.  Yes, you could scavenge the items in the cache but the cache itself would remain in memory. You could reuse caches, but how do you know when it's safe to reuse? You would have to maintain some metrics to known when to reuse, free, or scavenge the cache.  e.g. last access time.

Comment: The scenario that I've seen this applied to is a per user cache.  In that case I can imagine thousands of caches set up which could be a bit of memory plus each cache could start scavenging threads so there could be some performance impact there. These aren't insurmountable problems -- just that people should be aware of the potential issues and consider the impact of their design.

Comment: Yes, that's all about decision. Actually when using cache we should consider the pros and cons. Using cache is mainly to speed up data retrieval tasks, it's likely a decision between memory and speed. I agree that people should know this. If we know using cache will speed up our program a lot so we will use it.